# Default save location for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is it possible to change the default save location for Google Apps Scripts? It saves new files to the root directory of Drive by default, but it would be nice if you could change the save location to something like "My Drive > Apps Scripts". As far as I know, you can't even choose a location when saving, so if you don't want these files in the root directory you always have to go move them elsewhere.

Comment: Not possible. The folders in Google Drive are tags, not location: one file can be in multiple folders. The default state is having no tags.

Comment: Are saying you want to programmatically control where your files are saved during the execution of a particular script, or just overall no matter what script is running and change the default save location?

Comment: @Gerneio The latter. Basically say if a file is a Google Apps Script, then it will reside in this folder/location. For example if I open a new script and save it, it should go in this folder instead of root. Yes I know that Google Drive isn't the same as Windows, but for this example, I would say what I'm looking for would be equivalent to changing your default downloads directory from "C:\Users\username\Downloads" to "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Scripts".

Comment: Right, ok, well as @Meta already posted, that is not possible. However I would imagine that it is possible to build a script that can put files in the appropriate location. You'd then have to either run that script manually or set it on a timer with a trigger. That's probably about the only option you got.

Comment: If you create scripts using the Google Drive interface  "New" button while in whichever folder you want scripts to be kept in then that's where they will be. Firing up a new tab and starting at script.google.com will default as you described.

Comment: @Jonathon That's what I thought and that's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you create scripts using the Google Drive interface "New" button while in whichever folder you want scripts to be kept in then that's where they will be.

Firing up a new tab and starting at script.google.com will default as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standalone GAS script, place it in the desired location, such as an "App Scripts" folder. If the script creates a new Google Sheet, executing the code will produce the sheet in the same folder.